# Table In Use phpmyadmin - Xampp

Tags: mysql, xampp

i'm using xampp v3.2.2. But today one table is not working when I try to connect through php it return `Base Table or view not found: 1932 Table 'tablename' doesn't exist in engine` and when I try to repair it from localhost/phpmyadmin it gives me another error [Error on repair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oHxU.png) . Luckily I have a backup for this table but It doesn't let me create new table or delete this table. Please tell me what to do and I don't wanna create a new table with new name because then I will need to change this table name everywhere. Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: and one more thing when I click on database name it shows me all table name, type etc. Beside the table which is not working I get `IN USE` message. Thank you

Comment: Restart MySQL to see if that clears the problem.

Comment: nope that doesn't solve my problem. I did that so many times.

Comment: "Table 'tablename' doesn't exist in engine" Do you have a view or table named as "tablename' ? if not change the 'tablename' the name of your table....

Comment: to post here i changed it to tablename. The name of the table is settings

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I installed a new version of xampp removed old one and imported my backup.sql. Everything is working fine. Thank you guys.

Comment: that's not solve your problem, i got the same problem like you, i did uninstall more than 3 times, but sometimes table get in use again.